# Which is better when using provider instance in a new widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-provider

Let's say I've written my code as below.
I've got a provider called SampleProvider, and I'm using it in my main widget.

```
class SampleProvider extends ChangeNotifier {}

class MainWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SampleProvider provider = Provider.of<SampleProvider>(context);
  }
}
```

And then, I want to make a new widget and use this provider in the new widget.
There will be two choices.
First, I just instantiate another provider in the new widget as below.

```
class NewWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SampleProvider provider = Provider.of<SampleProvider>(context);
  }
}
```

Or, I can send it from the main widget to the new widget as a constructor parameter.
Like this:

```
class NewWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final SampleProvider provider;
  NewWidget(this.provider);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  }
}
```

I guess the first option is better because flutter draws a widget based on its build context, but I'm not sure.
I've googled it quite long, but there was no success.
Can anybody tell me whether I am right or wrong? Or Do they have no difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prefer the first solution, it's easier to refactor.

Suppose you need move `NewWidget` in your widget tree, you also need to modify the "paramter pass" code if you choose second solution, which is not necessary with first solution.

One of `Provider pacakage`'s purpose is avoid passing parameter deep in the widget tree by the way.

Answer (score 3):

Depend on preference not like first or second one.

Have an exception when obtaining Providers inside initState. What can I do?
This exception happens because you're trying to listen to a provider from a life-cycle that will never ever be called again.

It means that you either should use another life-cycle (build), or explicitly specify that you do not care about updates.

As such, instead of:

```
initState() {
  super.initState();
  print(context.watch<Foo>().value);
}
```

you can do:

```
Value value;

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final value = context.watch<Foo>.value;
  if (value != this.value) {
    this.value = value;
    print(value);
  }
}
```

which will print value whenever it changes (and only when it changes).

Alternatively, you can do:

```
initState() {
  super.initState();
  print(context.read<Foo>().value);
}
```

SRC: https://github.com/rrousselGit/provider#i-have-an-exception-when-obtaining-providers-inside-initstate-what-can-i-do

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I believe the first option is the better way, of the top of my head I can't think of any situation in which you would prefer the second option to the first.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use new widget as children of any other widget , first choice is better .
otherwise , second is better .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).